# Best practice to sync with 3rd party API running long jobs (javascript, node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, api

First of all, I am quite new to javascript and node.js. So it's quite possible there will be some nice and easy solution to my problem.

I have a small node.js application which calls 3rd party (REST) API to start jobs. 
As a response from the API, I get only a key which could be used to request status of current job. There are two dependent jobs, so I need to sync their start on my side.

**Example:**

Jobs A & B. They can be started calling these api's: http://host/start/A resp. http://host/start/B

Above API's return something like this:

```
{ 
  "job":"A",
  "key":"someRandomKey"
}
```

Then there is another API, to check the status (of any job): http://host/status/someRandomKey

As a result of this API I get:

```
{
  "key":"someRandomKey",
  "status":"[RUNNING|SUCCESSFUL|FAIL]"
}
```

I can start job B only after job A finished successfully!

**And now the question:**

How to effectively sync status of job A?

Once the job A was started (I got the job key), I can start a loop that will periodically check status of job A, until it is not successful. Here, I would probably use timeout, to check for change every 10s.

But I can't believe, there isn't some library or tool to do it for me better way. Any suggestions here?

Comment: There are better ways to design that API that don't require the other end to poll in order to know when it's done, but if you're stuck with polling the API for a status result, then there are no other options besides polling it on a timer.  The only option to play with is how often to poll it.

Answer (score 0):

Agee with @jfriend00 if you don't have access to modify the api then polling is the only option.
You can use some plugin for more easy integration though such as [Smartupdater](https://github.com/vkiryukhin/Smartupdater)